# Updating ComboBox in XAML without Somegrid.Items.Refresh()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I'm new in WPF+C# and starting to get a grip on it.

I want to update ComboBox inside DataGrid when program is running.
Unfortunately, ComboBox never show any selected item if I'm using Somegrid.Item.Refresh() to update DataGrid.

---

Here is the XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="Somegrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="SomebodY" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Somebody}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Somebody" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="SomethinG" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Something}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Something" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <TextBlock Text="SomewherE" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Somewhere}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Somewhere" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

Behind code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            someclassFoo.Somebody = new List<string>() { "Alan", "Benjamin" };

            observableSomeclassFoo.Add(someclassFoo);
            Somegrid.ItemsSource = observableSomeclassFoo;

        }


        public SomeclassFoo someclassFoo = new SomeclassFoo();
        private ObservableCollection<SomeclassFoo> _observableSomeclassFoo = new ObservableCollection<SomeclassFoo>();
        public ObservableCollection<SomeclassFoo> observableSomeclassFoo { get { return _observableSomeclassFoo; } }


        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Somebody(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb1 = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender;

            if (cb1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Alan")
            {
                someclassFoo.Something = new List<string>() { "Apple" };
            }
            else if (cb1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Benjamin")
            {
                someclassFoo.Something = new List<string>() { "Banana" };
            }

            //Somegrid.Items.Refresh();
        }


        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Something(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb2 = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender;

            if (cb2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Apple")
            {
                someclassFoo.Somewhere = new List<string>() { "Antartica" };
            }
            else if (cb2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Banana")
            {
                someclassFoo.Somewhere = new List<string>() { "Bedrock" };
            }

            //Somegrid.Items.Refresh();
        }


        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged_Somewhere(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cb3 = (System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox)sender;

            MessageBox.Show(cb3.SelectedItem.ToString().ToUpper() + " selected");
        }


    }
}
```

---

Another class

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class SomeclassFoo
    {
        public IList<string> Somebody { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Something { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Somewhere { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

How I can update the ComboBox *SomethinG* and ComboBox *SomewherE* without using *Somegrid.Item.Refresh()* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SomeclassFoo` type should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notifications:

```
public class SomeclassFoo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IList<string> _somebody;
    public IList<string> Somebody
    {
        get { return _somebody; }
        set { _somebody = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private IList<string> _something;
    public IList<string> Something
    {
        get { return _something; }
        set { _something = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private IList<string> _someWhere;
    public IList<string> Somewhere
    {
        get { return _someWhere; }
        set { _someWhere = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**How to: Implement Property Change Notification:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of refreshing the grid, remove the current source and set a new source:

`yourGrid.ItemsSource = null;`

`yourGrid.ItemsSource = yourDataSource;`